# Why do i keep getting an "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" from Redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, redis

So I am trying to get started with Redis Caching. I am trying to cache a User but i keep getting this "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" error.
Here is my getUser Controller code.

```
exports.getOne = async (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const cachedUser =  client.get('name');
    if(cachedUser){
      console.log(JSON.parse(cachedUser));
      return res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(cachedUser));
    }
    let user = await User.findById(id);
    if(!user) {
      return res.status(400).json('This user does not exist');
    }
    let newCachedUser = await client.set('name', JSON.stringify(user));
    if(newCachedUser){
      console.log('Succesfully cached')
    }
    throw error;
    console.log(error);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json(error.message)
  }
}
```

Here is the error i keep getting:

```
"Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"
```

Here is a copy of the user object i am trying to cache

```
{
    "_id": "62a31b9409d54491c84d4ebc",
    "name": "Oritom Harry",
    "email": "harry@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2b$10$eCPMuoQDg63x8nTKqTjDUO.mWWU1DVDLun9LT.iN.TE3tYM.OwqdC",
    "__v": 2,
    "question": [
      "62aa84a25b2d1ca611c4875f",
      "62aa8c0e24319c95b430dc45"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? What is the value of `cachedUser`? Why do you `throw error;`?

Comment: You can use the Redis CLI (or some other client) to check what the Redis database actually contains. Is this what you expect?

Comment: the mentioned document works for me, I would vote that the problematic document is a different one